# Fetch API call with Zapier + Prosperworks

Tags: post, curl, zapier, fetch-api

I'm trying to call the Prosperworks API through Code by Zapier. I can do this easy through curl, but for the life of me cannot get this POST call to work using fetch. Below is what I've got...any help appreciated. Thanks

```
fetch('https://api.prosperworks.com/developer_api/v1/people/fetch_by_email', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-PW-AccessToken': 'API_TOKEN',
    'X-PW-Application': 'developer_api',
    'X-PW-UserEmail': 'EMAIL'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({'email': input.email})
  }).then(function(res) {
     var people_id = res.id;
     return res.json();
  }).then(function(body) {
    callback(null, {id: 1234, rawHTML: body});
  }).catch(function(error) {
    callback("error");
  });
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run that code?

Comment: 404. resource not found.

Comment: OK, you should note that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the lead engineer on the ProsperWorks developer API. sideshowbarker is correct; we do not accept cross-origin requests from Zapier. Given that we offer Zapier integration, though, perhaps we should. I'll bring it up with the dev team and see if we can get that onto an upcoming release :)

Comment: Thanks Neil. Yes please do ask for the change. If you've already made the call to enable zapier, then shouldn't be anything undue in allowing the zapier tinkers to acces you in new ways. We'll post our good stuff out to the public when we create. So all good accrues to PW